# Input Signal Out Of range?

Tags: windows-xp, display

HI, I have a HP w1907 lcd and it's "optimal resolution" should be 1440x900 but when I set it to this resolution this message appears:

```
Input Signal Out Of range
Change Settings to 1440x900 - 60 Hz
```

so I triple checked the refresh rate and resolution and they are correct, any Ideas?

Comment: do you get a signal with any lower resolution?

Comment: yes, I am using 1280x800 right now... wich by the way sucks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:
Bought a new LCD

Answer (score 0):

Some possible causes I can think of:

1. Video driver not up to date (download from the manufacturer's site)
2. Video card is not as capable as the monitor
3. The monitor is branched on the wrong video exit (for example VGA)

Comment: 1.- Updated this morning  
2.-video card supports this and larger resolutions
3.- what do you mean by that =P

Comment: @Luis Garcia: You seem too well-organized for (3). So: (4) Hardware problem - check all monitor's settings and try it on another computer.

Comment: @harrymc: gonna try it out on my lap... I'll post results later, thanks